# Unable to append an array of images to another array swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, uicollectionview, alamofire

MY JSON:

`{
  "response" : {
    "start" : 0,
    "docs" : [
      {
        "enrollmentId" : [
          "KAR\KDF6"
        ],
        "fieldName2" : [
          "Languages"
        ],
        "locality" : [
          "Boret"
        ],
        "active" : [
          true
        ],
        "sex" : [
          "Male"
        ],
        "latitude" : [
          12.457
        ],
        "city" : [
          "Booer"
        ],
        "imageData" : [
          "data:image\/png;base64,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"
        ],
        "fieldValue2" : [
          "English, Hindi, Kannada"
        ],
        "fieldValue1" : [
          "11 years"
        ],
        "state" : [
          "Kerr"
        ],
        "id" : "sdffsdfsdf",
        "email" : [
          "me@some.com"
        ],
        "longitude" : [
          77.552492
        ],
        "firstName" : [
          "Prashya"
        ],
        "_version_" : 145434759168,
        "experience" : [
          12
        ],
        "caseTypes" : [
          "some some"
        ],
        "lastName" : [
          "Bhaer"
        ],
        "mode" : [
          "Lawyer"
        ],
        "fieldName1" : [
          "Experience"
        ]
      },
      {
        "state" : [
          "Rater"
        ],
        "languages" : [
          "English",
          "Hindi",
          "Kannada"
        ],
        "lastName" : [
          "K"
        ],
        "firstName" : [
          "Rresr"
        ],
        "sex" : [
          "Male"
        ],
        "caseTypes" : [
          "So many"
        ],
        "enrollmentId" : [
          "KARdsfs"
        ],
        "mobile" : [
          98453445
        ],
        "id" : "Rajfsdsg",
        "imageData" : [
          "data:image\/png;base64,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"
        ],
        "active" : [
          true
        ],
        "mode" : [
          "Lawyer"
        ],
        "city" : [
          "Bangalore"
        ],
        "_version_" : 15214536,
        "email" : [
          "me@me.com"
        ],
        "experience" : [
          18
        ],
        "locality" : [
          "bajaj"
        ]
      }
    ],
    "numFound" : 2
  },
  "responseHeader" : {
    "status" : 0,
    "QTime" : 1,
    "params" : {
      "q" : "mode:(\"Lawyer\", \"CA\") AND active:true AND city:(\"Boret\") AND locality:(\"bajaj\") AND caseTypes:(\"fly fly\")",
      "wt" : "json"
    }
  }
}`

I've declared a global array `private var items = [UIImage]()` and `private var cellsIsOpen = [Bool]()` .

I'm converting the bas64 imageData strings obtained from JSON data and returning an array of `UIImage` like

```
public func loadimages(url: String!) -> [UIImage]{
    let unsafe = url
    var data1 = [UIImage]()
    let bingo = NSURL(string: unsafe!)
    Alamofire.request(.GET, bingo!)
        .validate()
        .responseJSON{ response in
            switch response.result{
            case .Success:

                let json33 = JSON(data: response.data!)

                let allImageStrings = json33["response"]["docs"].flatMap { $0.1["imageData"].first?.1}


                for Bro in allImageStrings{

                    let url = NSURL(string: Bro.string!)
                    let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)!
                    let image = UIImage(data: data)


                    data1.append(image!)

                }

                self.items = data1


                //print(self.items.count)

            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }


    }


return data1

}
```

And in

```
override public func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

print(self.items.count)
return self.items.count

}
```

the count is showing 0. The Array `items` is not getting appended AT ALL. How do I append it? I'm even trying to do

```
 override public func viewDidLoad() {

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    itemSize = CGSize(width: 214, height: 264)
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let gt: [UIImage] = loadimages("someurl&wt=json")


    items.append(gt) //Error: Cannot convert value of type '[UIImage]' to expected argument type 'UIImage'        
    print(items.count)        

}
```

And there it this function

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    guard let cell = cell as? CollectViewCell else { return }

   // var index = indexPath.row % 4
    //let info = items

    for item in items{

      cell.backgroundImageView.image = item


    }

  cell.cellIsOpen(cellsIsOpen[indexPath.row], animated: false) //Here
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

*Here, it crashes saying `Index out of range`.

Help Please?

Comment: It's because your request is async and your method is returning before the data is loaded into the array.

Comment: @conarch suggest a fix please?

Comment: @kye with code please? A beginner still. :(

Comment: @Dershowitz123 does your commented out print statement in the request print anything other than 0?

Comment: No problem, give me a couple minutes

Comment: One simple option would be to call a "reload" method after you finish building the array, rather than making that array be the return value.

Comment: @NSGangster no it's just 0 and nothing else. :(

Comment: Alright this confirms my theory you are either parsing the strings wrong or the value you get back is 0. If you don't parse anything `AllImageStrings` will be count 0 and your for loop will never get called. Won't append anything, etc.

Comment: Without seeing json I can't really help you debug that issue anymore.

Comment: index out of range is another unrelated issue. Check to see if `cellIsOpen` array is count 0. Also don't call `reloadData()` in a dataSource or delegate method like that you can run into an infinite loop and freeze up your UI.

Comment: Can you print Json and add it to question please? Pretty sure you are parsing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem might be with your Alamofire request. Either it fails and so nothing it appended since you append under your success case, or you're trying to print the items before anything is loaded because it is an asynchronous request. Try appending an image under your failure case.

Also the reason you are getting the error "Cannot convert value of type '[UIImage]' to expected argument type 'UIImage' " is because you are trying to append an entire array to an array, when you need to just append a single element, in this case, a UIImage.

try this to test the size of your array instead

```
let gt: UIImage = UIImage()
items.append(gt)
print(items.count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire is nice that it grabs the main thread in the callback making UI easy to update. Your first call to collectionView's dataSource methods will be before the request is done. However. calling `collectionView.reloadData()` after setting `self.items` should solve your issue.

```
     case .Success:

                    let json33 = JSON(data: response.data!)
                    let data = json33["response"].stringValue.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
                    let json = JSON(data: data!)
                    let allImageStrings = json["docs"].flatMap { $0["imageData"].first?.stringValue }


                    for Bro in allImageStrings{
                        let imgString = Bro.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("data:image/png;base64," , withString: "")
                        let imgData = imgString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
                        let image = UIImage(data: imgData)


                        data1.append(image!)

                    }

                    self.items = data1


                    //Add
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

All data source methods are recalled on the collectionView when `reloadData()` is called so if you have successfully created images (This may be an underlying problem as well), you should get a count the next time these dataSource methods are called.

Comment: @Dershowitz123 try replacing all of your code in your .Success case with the code here.

Comment: I am able to get the images and display them properly with the code I've posted. But the problem now is with the (willdisplaycell_:) function which I've posted. It is saying index out of range. :(

Comment: 2 things. Do you have an array called cellIsOpen and a function called cellIsOpen? The other thing to do, since you need to pass in cell at current indexPath. is just pass in cell itself like so. `cell.cellIsOpen(cell, animated: false)` . Maybe post function `cellIsOpen` code so I can take a look

Comment: change line to `cell.cellIsOpen(cell.isOpen, animated: false)`

Comment: Then when I open a cell and reopen another one, it crashes. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114286/discussion-between-nsgangster-and-dershowitz123).

Answer (score 0):

## Try this

Replace this array type

```
var data1 = [UIImage]()
```

with this type of array for type safety sometime array not getting correct format so failed to append value
Use this Array:-

```
var data1 = [AnyObject]()
```

I hope this will help you.